# Entity Framework - Is it possible to share the DbCompiledModel and metadata information stored in memory between different AppDomains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

We have a large ERP based application that utilizes several .net technologies in several different projects. The solution structure is similar to:

**Class libraries:**

- Core (infrastructure, extensions, utilities, etc)
- Business (tightly coupled POCO’s with mappings to Gentle.Net) a legacy layer that will be refactored into web services.
- Domain (poco objects reflected from the database, created for EF)
- Data (EF dbcontext, mapping configuration to domain objects)

  - InstanceContext = db context for all the tables (~400 mapped tables)
  - ReadOnlyContext = db context for all of the database views (~500 mapped views)

**Web services:**

- Webservices (legacy asmx services)
- API (Web API)

**Front ends:**

- WebForms app (90% of the front-end)
- WebForms app stuck on .net 3.5 in legacy cas mode to allow decent exporting performance of local rdlc reports.
- MVC app (newer front-end development here)
- Various WinForms smart client apps customized for clients’ needs

We are gradually refactoring the application to hopefully decouple some of the business logic routines. We started with replacing Gentle.Net ORM (a very old ORM that has treated us well over the years) with Entity Framework. However, we are running into an issue with memory utilization (not a memory leak).

At first it seemed very painless, as we ran the EF reverse POCO generator against the existing database and implemented the DbConfiguration feature to generate an EDMX file (for faster startup times).

Now that most of the front-end and web service projects are using EF, memory requirements have sky rocketed. Each AppDomain requires ~500MB of memory to hold the db contexts, this happens during initialization of EF. We have done extensive memory profiling and can confirm that our context usage is being disposed of properly. It appears the DbCompiledModels are retained in memory forever as EF needs that cached data to operate.

I *could* merge the MVC/Webforms, ASMX/WebAPI projects together to reduce the memory required as that would eliminate 2 AppDomains. But I am wondering if there’s a way I could share the cached entity models\mapping information between the different AppDomains. Like a distributed cache, but for the DbCompiledModels?

Each project runs as an application under a single website in IIS, and they will always use the same database context\mappings, so they don’t necessarily need to be instanced per AppDomain.

***note** – while there are better ways to refactor this issue, they require a significant amount of time to refactor and test due to the size of the application. Fixing the low hanging fruit will give us some breathing room. If each application could share the in-memory mapping information entity framework requires on startup, that would cut out memory utilization by 50%.

Answer (score 0):

> Each AppDomain requires ~500MB of memory to hold the db contexts, this
>   happens during initialization of EF.

I would suggest that maybe you're holding onto your DbContext too long? Or your database structure is massive. Its ok to use and dispose of the DbContext as often as you like, so make your method calls as small as possible - and remember to register the DbContexts as scoped so that they are adequately disposed of

Comment: This is during application initialization. Before we even use the DbContext. We are disposing of the contexts properly. EF compiles the entire Db model in memory, this is what I want to distribute between applications.

Comment: Correction, this happens during the first query to the context. In the global.asax, we can wrap the context in a using (bypassing DI for testing purposes), and memory will increase by ~500MB after EF initializes.

Comment: How are you configuring the model? Annotations or Code First?

Comment: Code first, a configuration class is generated per model using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration.

Comment: Hey Robert, I took a closer look at the web global.asax begin/end request events. It appears the DI container is being resolved in a non-injected way, ie:  DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<>(). I will do some research to see if the LifeTimeManager does not take affect when explicitly calling DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<>() (Unity DI btw).

Comment: That only shaved off about 20MB. Each AppDomain instance still requires around ~480MB per. This is after forcing GC on context initialization. Would still be interested in sharing this between AppDomains. Splitting up the schema into multiple contexts is not really something we can do right now.

Comment: @JTHope Did you ever find a solution to this?